# jQuery syntax highlighting in PhpStorm with NPM/Gulp/Webpack

Tags: jquery, laravel, npm, gulp, phpstorm

I have a Laravel application using NPM and Gulp to manage my JS assets.

I'm registering jQuery via `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')`.

Everything works properly in my application, but in my view files wherever I use jQuery via `$('selector').method()` PhpStorm shows a syntax error on the `$` which says something like `invalid number of arguments (3 expected)`.

I tried going into PhpStorm settings -> JS Libraries and adding jquery in manually (adding the jquery.js and jquery.min.js from the node_modules directory). But, that doesn't seem to help.

So, any thoughts on how to get PhpStorm to recognize the $ properly?

Comment: `Ctrl+click` on `$` - what definition is opened? I'd suggest using JQuery2.0 library for completion:  settings -> JS Libraries, press `Download...`, select "Official Libraries" from dropdown, choose JQuery2.0

Comment: It jumps into a Datatables plugin file `$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnColReorder = function ( oSettings, iFrom, iTo ) { ... }`.

I tried adding the JQuery2.0 Official Library and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with the same plugin. I mean I have datatables JS in one of the directories as it's used by the project. But it is somehow overriding $ of jquery. It works but it is still annoying.